# Intellij and changes tab

Tags: intellij-idea

In the changes tab, IDEA shows a bunch of files which, when I view with the diff viewer, have no differences. Then when I commit to svn these files are committed as well. Is there a way I can only view/commit files which are actually different?

Answer (score 1):

In the Show Diff window, what is Ignore Whitespace set to (in the top left corner)? If it is set to anything other than 'Do not ignore', try changing it and seeing if that is the difference in the files.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the VCS, Perforce has "Revert Unchanged Files" in the Perforce VC menu. While Git only checks in files that are changed (checks diff when committing). Otherwise it might be the above answer that Idea has a setting for ignoring/hiding whitespace only changes)

Answer (score 0):

Could there be property changes on those files? Right click, then select Subversion -> Properties Diff with Local