# Ignore whitespace changes in IntelliJ changebars

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a file from our repository where I ran auto-indent (because it was a mess), and now the whole file is marked by blue changebars (down the right hand side of the editor window), making it difficult to find my changes.

I am already ignoring whitespace changes in the diff window (as described here: [Intellij and changes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631531/intellij-and-changes-tab)), is there a way to also do this in the editor window?

Comment: One of the developers on my team always sends a PR where there's lot of noise in Git diff. Lines haven't changed but show up in the diff. Is it because of the whitespaces?

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find a way to completely ignore whitespaces, but IntelliJ (I'm using version 2016) lets you set an option to color whitespace-only changes differentely:

**Editor -> General -> Different color for lines with whitespace-only modifications**

which helps tremendously.

Comment: Setting is true by default in version 2017

Answer (score 2):

At the moment [idea 13.5] it seems that is not possible to ignore spaces in the standard editor. You can open a support ticket

We also faced this in the company due the different codestyles used, at the end we settle for:

- setting a common codestyle that everyone editing the code should [actually **must**] follow
- reformat the whole codebase to the given codestyle
- recommit the formatted code [without any addition or deletion, just the reformat]

It took just a bit of time, but at the end now we are working far better. In this way from that moment onward, we would have all the time the code that would aesthetically the same trough next versions.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you want Intellij to use the --ignore-all-space or --ignore-space-change upon a merge.

My developer team also deals with this challenge because we have different code formatting preferences.  The result is every merge is painful for no reason.  The team loves being able to have their code formatting, but this negates it.

As of now there is no solution.  Intellij has the technology to ignore whitespace, so fixing this is really just adding a check box on the merge diff screen or even in the version control settings.

There is a feature requests IDEA-107714
Please up vote it!
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107714

Answer (score 2):

You can completely disable the highlight of whitespace modified lines in :

> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> VSC -> Editor Gutter -> Whitespace-modified lines

And then uncheck the background color :
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

> View --> Active Editor --> Show whitespaces

this is guaranteed to solve your problem